# Windows RegSetValueEx Funtion Error with REG_SZ C++

Tags: windows

```
HKEY hkey;
LPCSTR data = "HelloWrold\0";
if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Sample", 0,KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey))
{
    cout << "Registry Open SUccess" << endl;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegSetValueEx(hkey, L"NAME", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)(data), strlen(data)+1))
        cout << "Value Set Success" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Value Set Failed" << endl;
}
else
    cout << "Registry Open Failed " << GetLastError() << endl;
```

when i use this code the code works fine, but in registry I'm not getting `Helloworld` but getting some chinese characters, any suggestion what to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Why does misdetected Unicode text tend to show up as Chinese characters?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953)

> If you take an ASCII string and cast it to Unicode, the results are usually nonsense Chinese.

Your project setting are probably defining `UNICODE` and your call to `RegSetValueEx` ends up calling `RegSetValueExW` but you are passing it a narrow C-style string.

Change it to `RegSetValueExA(hkey, "NAME", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)(data), strlen(data)+1)` or change `data` to be a Unicode string (WCHAR/LPWSTR).

You can catch this sort of error in C++ by changing `(LPBYTE)(data)` to `(LPBYTE)const_cast<LPTSTR>(data)`.